# Binding To the Parent of A Context Menu Which is A Templated Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, .net-4.0, datagrid

In a WPF .Net 4 application have a master detail situation where a datagrid has rows which can have the detail information as found in the RowDetailsTemplate which has an internal datagrid.

Within the RowDetailsTemplate is a grid to hold the sub details which has a context menu. The problem found is when binding the CommandTarget of one of the details' MenuItem, I am unable to target *that* details datagrid as *generated by the template*. The below binding ends up getting the Master datagrid and not the containing datagrid which is holding the details information/contextmenu.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgEditScript" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentScript}">

<DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="commands:ScriptingCommands.SetChecked"
                    Executed="CheckAllAfter" />
</DataGrid.CommandBindings>

<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SubCommands}">
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Check All From Selected"
                              Command="commands:ScriptingCommands.SetChecked"
                              CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="Images/checkboxes.png" />
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem when using the above Realtive source binding, it gives me the dgEditScript grid (top level) and not the parent of the context menu, the unnamed holding DataGrid which the context menu was launched from.

How do I get the sub grid in the binding; to target the parent of the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, you have a collections of items, and you want the context menu to be attached to the selected item (when you're right clicking on it ...)

Here's some similar code I'm using:

```
<ListBox x:Name="name_here"  
      ItemsSource="{Binding source_collection_name}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding property_name_on_VM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       >
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header ="Edit Item"   Command="{Binding EditItem_Command}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding property_name_on_VM}"
            />
            <MenuItem Header ="Delete Item" Command="{Binding DeleteItem_Command}" 
                       CommandParameter="{Binding property_name_on_VM}"
            />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

This way, whenever you click on an item (or right click), it's selected, and then you just send that item as a command parameter, so you have the item you need.

Hope this helps.